# Change SSH port default to 1457 on HP EI 5500

Tags: switch, hp, hp-comware

I need to change SSH port default to 1457 on my HP L3 switch.

I search on net but haven't found anything

Can anyone help me.??

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe this feature exists on the ComWare OS. I have never seen it done or anyone request to do this. It would be worth contacting HP support and see if there is a secret command can be used in a developer mode of some sort.

Comment: Thanks,
there is another port 7547 wan management port.
I need to disable that port can you please assist me with this.??

Comment: Ok got it.

`system-view -> cwmp -> undo cwmp enable`

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Good to see you got it sorted.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProCurve-based HP switches offer this ability within the

> [no] ip ssh port

command, but Comware-based devices do not have any such feature.